# Android Fingerprint Scanning using Samsung device

Tags: android, fingerprint

am looking to write an App which will store the fingerprint of the people using it & later use it to authenticate them. Now, this App will be placed in a public place, and so there will be thousands of users. So, I need to store that many fingerprints. I tried a simple App with the [Samsung PASS SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/release-note/view.do?v=R000000009), and a Samsung tablet with fingerprint recognition built in. It worked, but looks like it is restricting to three fingerprints only. So, a maximum of three fingerprints can be saved & authenticated with, is what I see. Is this true? Is it possible to save thousands of fingerprints & use them in the App? Or is there any other company (other than Samsung) which offers this capability?

Comment: *So, a maximum of three fingerprints can be saved & authenticated with, is what I see* per device, i assume?

Comment: @TimCastelijns the sample App I tried using a tutorial opens up the Settings page when trying to register the fingerprint. And after I register three fingerprints, the 'add' button in the 'Settings' page is disabled.

Comment: So you can only register 3 prints per app per device. Why is that a problem? do you expect more than 3 people to use your app on the same device? Normally a user has their own device

Comment: @TimCastelijns this is going to be an App in a public place. So many people (possibly thousands) will use the App.

Comment: Can you check the sample code to see whether the limit of 3 is a software restriction? Perhaps you can simple remove the limit

Comment: no @TimCastelijns . there is no such thing specifically mentioned, but the limit seems to be there in the hardware, as far as I can see.

Comment: So you actually plan to put the device rather than the app in a public place and want multiple users to be able to authenticate themselves on it?

Comment: Unless the fingerprint is being sent over a network connection to some server it's just being stored on the specific device and the limit is 3 fingerprints per device. Try this: install the app on two different phones, store three fingerprints on one phone, attempt to add a fingerprint on the other phone. I suspect this will work based on what you've said about the app so far.

Comment: An external fingerprint sensor would probably be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this problem is a (totally intentional) limitation from the manufacturer (such as Samsung, Apple...). They have done their job: prevent that biometric data doesn't leave the phone. SImple as that. I don't know if there is any "illegal" method to retrieve that data to work freely with it.

Maybe you can try another approach: A small device with Linux (such a Raspberry Pi if you don't mind the desktop speed) with a USB fingerprint reader attached